# Webpack default parameters es6

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm not able to transpile es6 default parameters with webpack.
My current setup is:

```
var path    = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./main.js"],
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: './bundle.js'},
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve('../js'), path.resolve('../js/node_modules')],
      extensions: ['*', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
            {
                test: /(\.jsx?$|\.es6?$)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    plugins: [
                      'transform-es2015-arrow-functions',
                      'transform-es2015-block-scoping'
                    ],
                    presets: ['es2016', 'react']
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"',
        'global': {}, // bizarre lodash(?) webpack workaround
        'global.GENTLY': false // superagent client fix
    })
    ],
    target: "node"
};
```

[image]

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-parameters/

Comment: Seems like you may want to use `babel-preset-env` instead of hardcoding this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the parameters `transform plugins` to `babel`.

```
plugins: [
    'transform-es2015-arrow-functions',
    'transform-es2015-block-scoping',
    'transform-es2015-parameters'
],
```

See [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-parameters/)

Comment: Thanks for the list of plugins, I was looking for them in the wrong place.